# How to debug joomla components while developing them

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla2.5

I am writing my first joomla component and while I'm getting the hang of how joomla works, I don't know how I can effectively debug and run tests on my component before installing it in joomla. So my question is: How do you go about writing a joomla component. What parts should I write first and how do I test them?

Example: A component that gets information from database and displays it. How can I write the database part (model) and test it to see if it works as expected, without having to write the rest of the component (view and controller)?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.Read the FAQ before asking question.Try something before asking  any question and if you are stuck anywhere ask us we will help you.Dont ask question blindly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to understand how to setup your machine for development. You don't need a complete component to install it on Joomla!

This is by no means a complete answer, just a few directions which you can follow:

**1. Developing** - Understand how Joomla! works: as a beginner before going to much harder material, it's important to get your component to work first (starting isn't easy). Learn how to use the Joomla! Platform / Framework to build your components, check code in the core components.

**2. Unit Testing -** After you have a working component, if you want to test parts of it, do some search on the topic Unit Testing / PHPUnit. The article [How to use PHPUnit in Joomla](http://www.waltercedric.com/joomlacms/2076-using-phpunit-to-test-develop-joomla-extensions-in-phpstorm) helped me a lot on how to test a method from a controller / model I've built.

**3. Debugging your code** - learn how to use a debugger in your IDE (like XDebug or Zend Debugger).

**4. System Tests** - in the end you may want to automate some tasks you do manually - have a look at [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)

A couple of resources:

- [Joomla! Official Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Main_Page)
- [Learn the Art of Joomla!® from master developer Andrew Eddie](http://learn.theartofjoomla.com/)
- [Joomla! Programming - By Mark Dexter, Louis Landry](http://www.joomla.org/joomla-press-official-books.html)